# Jupyter Lab - menu panel is invisible

Tags: jupyter-lab, menubar

I recently downloaded jupyter lab in Linux, but found that it doesn't have a menu bar.
This is my screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZTxJ.png)
I tried reinstall jupyter lab but it didn't work.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you install JupyterLab? Previously when someone had this issue they had two conflicting installations of different versions and removing the old version helped.

Comment: By pip. How could I be sure I don't have two conflicting installations? I have installed and uninstalled many times.

Comment: Do you happen to use an old (<14.1) Safari version? See https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12862

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it solves my problem. I'm using Chrome 75 and when I switch to jupyter lab 3.4.3, the menu panel can work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue launching 'jupyter-lab' on Linux RHE7.9 which opens jupyter lab server in the default browser Mozilla Firefox.

fix:
Chrome displayed the proper jupyter menu bar

Installed rpm for google-chrome
Launched google-chrome
URL'd the same jupyter lab server (that did not display correctly in firefox)

Chrome displayed the proper jupyter menu bar
.. and BTW using chrome simultaneously solved the common editor ctrl-z 'undo' issue I was trying to address (so ctrl-z now undoes last text change in editor when editor cell is active).

#note you can launch jupyterlab also without browser so firefox doesn't come up, eg:

> python3 -m jupyterlab --no-browser
> google-chrome

paste in chrome url, eg:
http://localhost:8888/lab?token=a1d12asdfsdasdfasdfadssasdf90a9